# asp.net Twitter Bootstrap TempData.Add(Alerts.Error error when adding two errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the twitter bootstrap nuget package for MVC.

When posting to my controller, and checking for errors however, if I have more than one error in my model, I get the following error when trying to add a second alert to TempData:

`An item with the same key has already been added.`

```
    //
    // POST: /Customer/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // save to database etc
            // redirect to action
        }
        foreach (var c in errors)
        {
            TempData.Add(Alerts.ERROR, c.ErrorMessage);  // Error is reported here
        }
```

The error messages are difference, as shown below - so it must be that Alerts.ERROR is only allowed once:
[image: ss]

Is there any way of adding two `Alerts.Error` error messages to `TempData` - or should I just concatenate a string, and add one error with combined error messages?

If I change the TempData code to:

**TempData.Add(Alerts.ERROR, errors.Select(c => c.ErrorMessage).ToArray());**

...the view renders as:

[image: ss2]

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `TempData.Add(Alerts.ERROR, errors.Select(c => c.ErrorMessage).ToArray())` and iterate over the errors in your view?

Comment: Hi - thank you - I tried that, but it just says System.String[] in the view (I've added a screenshot to the post).

Comment: Yes -- you need to iterate over the errors, something like: `if (TempData[Alerts.ERROR] != null && TempData[Alerts.ERROR].Length > 0) { foreach(string message in TempData[Alerts.ERROR]) { <div>@message</div> }}`

Answer (score 1):

`TempData` is a dictionary, so it makes sense that trying to add a duplicate key causes an exception. Depending on how you show the contents of `TempData`, you either want to concatenate the error messages into one string, or use a key that has a `Guid` appended to it (thereby making the key unique every time).

One possible workaround (within your loop):

```
if (TempData.ContainsKey(Alerts.ERROR))
{
    string temp = TempData[Alerts.ERROR].ToString();
    TempData[Alerts.ERROR] = string.Concat(temp, c.ErrorMessage);
}
else
{
    TempData.Add(Alerts.ERROR, c.ErrorMessage);
}
```

This naively assumes you've previously formatted your error messages, and will produce one long string. If you're using, say, a `<ul>` to display the errors, you would wrap each error message in a `<li></li>`, then concat.